# Send multiple commands to sleeping Xbee module

Tags: xbee

I have an xbee module in cyclic sleep mode that sleep for about 5 sec, then wake up for 500ms and the go to sleep again and so on... I need to send multiple commands to this module in api mode but I have a problem... when it sleep only the last message is sent from coordinator. In detail I need to set a digital pin in high state for about 200 ms and then in low state again... the problem is when the commands are sent when the module is sleeping... when it wake up only the second command (digital pin to low state) is sent from coordinator, so nothing happens. Any solution? Is there any possibility to send more commands in api mode in a single frame?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which XBee module are you using?  Some of the modules support timeouts on their digital I/O.  You can configure the module to revert to its configured value after some elapsed time (in multiples of 100ms).

That would be a more reliable way to generate a 200ms pulse on one of the digital outputs.

I'm not sure which modules support this feature -- check in X-CTU or the documentation.  The commands at ATT0 through ATT9 to set timeouts on D0-D9 and ATQ0 through ATQ4 to set timeouts on P0-P4.

It's possible this is only available in the XBee Wi-Fi I have been using, and not the sleeping radios you're using.

Comment: I'm using a Series 2 module (non PRO version). This solution is perfect if it works. Tomorrow I give it a try. Thank you in adavance

Comment: Looking at the configuration of 21A7 firmware for the XB24-ZB, and I don't see those settings.  If you need a 200ms pulse, you should consider a hardware solution triggered by a change on the digital I/O pin, since you won't be able to reliably time it with remote AT commands.

Comment: The exact product is XB24-Z7WIT-004. I tried to search this AT command in the XCTU panel but without success...

Comment: The module is configured as an end device. What I want to obtain is a remote push-button, so an high pulse with a similar to human press-and-release delay before to put the pin again in low state. Is there a way to do this in a single API frame (input high/delay/input low) ??

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do it in a single API frame.  For reliability, you should look into a hardware solution that converts the low-to-high edge into a 200ms pulse.  This way you can have any amount of time between your two messages and you'll always get the proper pulse width.